# How do I change the onCreate method in a JavaFX controller

Tags: java, javafx

I have a fxml file controller called mainController.java. What I want to do is when the view is visible with this code:

```
Stage.show();
```

I want to execute some methods that are inside the controller file so I can change some things before the program is visible. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Initializable Interface which is called in JavaFX-Applications before the root element is completely processed: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html#initialize%28java.net.URL,%20java.util.ResourceBundle%29)

If your controller implements this interface, you have to implement the initializable-method.

A Controller-class gets constructed, then all @FXML fields and methods get injected and after that, you can access them in your initialize()-method.

Comment: I'd say "can implement" is the imprecise here. Since the controller has to be non-abstract, adding the interface means the method needs to be implemented. Also IMHO the explanation of the benefits of this approach are a bit misleading. You could also check services in a constructor (using the `initialize` method only means you can modify the injected instances according to the results).

Comment: You are right, if Initializable is implemented, initialize needs to be implemented. Also it depends on the services if you use a constructor or the initialize()-method. With initialize(), you can access the attributes and methods annotated by @FXML in your controller-class. External resources can be also accessed in the constructor. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers